# Finding the roots or interval in which the (roots) lie of the given equation.

Tags: polynomials, cubics

If an equation $$\frac{1}{x-3} + \frac{1}{x-4} + \frac{1}{x-5}+ \frac{1}{x-7}=0 $$ has been given to us then how can we find out--
1) ***the number of roots of the equation*** ??...if it was one of those easy polynomials I could have easily done it..but here it is different..also

2)can we find out ***what the roots are*** with only this much information[ any hint would suffice in this part ..no need to solve it ..fully...that's my job!!]..or even if this can't be done

3)can we ***make an approximate graph***{not an exact one[just approximate]} so that we can at least tell in which ***interval the roots lie.***.and also tell what the ***interval is***??

Edit:
I have already done this
( ***removing the denominator and assuming that $x\neq 3,4,5,7$ otherwise denominator will become equal to zero which is not allowed***) so here is the new equation I  got..
$$(x-4)(x-5)(x-7)+(x-5)(x-7)(x-3)+(x-5)(x-4)(x-3)+(x-7)(x-4)(x-3)=0$$

But what to do now..how to get the things I mentioned above..in the question..

Comment: Have you tried clearing denominators?

Comment: @Unit I have edited the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial is the first derivative of $f(x)=(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-7).$ By inspection, we have  $f(x)>0$ for $x<3$, for $x\in (4,5)$,and for $x>7$. And  $f(x)<0$ for $x\in (3,4)$ and for $x\in (5,7).$  So $f(x)$ has a negative-valued local minimum in $(3,4)$ ,and also in $(5,7)$,and a positive-valued local maximum in $(4,5)$.These are the $3$ points where $f'=0.$

Comment: Did you just got lucky ..or this derivative thing would have worked even if in place of $3,4,5,7$ ..any general natural numbers $a,b,c,d$ were there...would I have been able to do this thing even if I was given any other numbers in place of $3,4,5,7$ take $473,54,23,78$ for example...

Comment: Of course any 4 numbers will do. Write them in my proof in place of 3,4,5,7 in increasing order.

Comment: OK..so since $f'$ was coming equal to zero between three intervals $(3,4)(4,5)(5,7)$ so the equation I wrote in the question above above also has three roots in this given interval ..right??

Comment: Nice +1. Or you could say $f(x)$ clearly has four distinct real roots, so it's derivative must have three, one in each interval between the roots. As the derivative is a cubic, that's all the roots.

Comment: Very well phrased,

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply with right terms and remove denominator to get a polynomial of degree three. You can do the rest!

Comment: I have already done this.. See the question I edited it..

Comment: HINT : take the help of general wavy curve method to find the interval and roots after removing the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

you dont want to multiply out. let $f$ be defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-3} + \frac{1}{x-4} + \frac{1}{x-5}+ \frac{1}{x-7}.$  then we have the following:

(a)  $f = \frac 4x +\cdots \text{ for } x \to \pm \infty$

(b) $\lim_{x \to k-} f(x) = -\infty, \lim_{x \to k+} f(x) = \infty, \text{ for }k = 3, 4, 5, 7$

the graph is monotone decreasing in every one of the intervals $(-\infty, 3), (3, 4), \cdots , (7, \infty)$

therefore by the intermediate values theorem, $f$ has $3$ simple roots one in each open intervals $(3, 4), (4, 5), 5, 7).$

Comment: Do you mean $(3,4)(4,5)(5,7)$ in the last line...??

Comment: @Freelancer, yes. i just corrected it.